# Find $A$ such that $f(0) = A$ and there exists $f'(0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, piecewise-continuity

Let
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
(e^{3x}-3e^x+2)/x^2 & :x \neq 0\\
A & :x=0\\
\end{cases}$$
I'm supposed to find $A$ such that there exists $f'(0)$. My attempt:

First, I found $A$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, using de l'Hospital's rule to calculate $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f(x)$.
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
(e^{3x}-3e^x+2)/x^2 & :x \neq 0\\
3 & :x=0\\
\end{cases}$$
Then I calculated one-sided limits of the difference quotient at $x=0$ using de l'Hospital's rule (but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do so - I've read that applying this rule to the definition of derivative may lead to some kind of circular reasoning).
$$\lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0^{-}}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(0)=4$$
Is this solution correct? Wolfram Alpha and Desmos tell me that $f'(0)=0$ for $A=3$. However, when I set $A$ to a different value (meaning the function isn't continuous at $x=0$ and hence not differentiable) I still get $f'(0)=0$, which is quite confusing.

Comment: The derivation works only when $f(0)=A=3$  Otherwise the difference quotient blows up.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "same result" for$A\ne 3$?  In that case $f'(0)$ does not exist.

To get continuity, use power series for the numerator: $1+3x+\frac{9x^2}{2}-3(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2})+2=3x^2$  Therefore $\lim_{x\to 0}3$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, wolfram says f'(0)=4
[image]

Comment: I'm supposed to find A such that there exists f′(0). That sentence is bad, since for certain function we can have a situation that f(x) is contiuous but not differentiable at x=0. As you know, even  we know that it is continuous at set X, we still can't say whether it is differentiable at certain points inside set X

Comment: That doesn't prove he is right, it just proves that wolfram alpha agrees with him! 

Answer (score 1):

You have calculated $A$ correctly now for finding $f^{\prime}(0)$
$$\begin{align} f^{\prime}(0) &= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{3x}-3e^x+2}{x^2} - 3}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^{3x}-3e^x+2-3x^2}{x^3}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^{3x}-e^x-2x}{x^2}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{3e^{3x}-e^x-2}{2x} \\
&= \frac{9}{2}\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{3x}-1}{3x} - \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^x -1}{x} \\
&= 4 \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)= 4x+3$ if $x = 0$

(filled needed 7  more characters)

Comment: that way the function is continuous and derivable 1 time

Comment: I see, but why is $A=4x+3$ better than $A=3$?

Comment: Because if A = 3 then the side limits of the derivative in x=0 is $f'(0)=4$ but at $f'(0)=0$ so the derivative is not continuous at x=0.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. How is $f'(0)=4$ and $f'(0)=0$ at the same time?

Comment: The limit by the right side, the limit by the left side and the value at the point.

Comment: $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f'(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}f'(x)=4$$ $$f'(0)=0$$

Comment: So $f'(x)$ is dicontinuous at $0$. (f not differenciable)